# What is KeyEvent.VK_1

Tags: java

I found an example on the web to create a tabbedPane. The example has the code like as bellows

```
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);  
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_2);
```

Would you tell me what key in the keyboard to have action for KeyEvent.VK_1 and  KeyEvent.VK_2?

I want to use "Tab" key in the keyboard to switch the panel in the tabbedPane. Would you tell me how. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: For the tabbedPane you can press both alt key and the number 1 key.  Alt+1 (KeyEvent.VK_1) to access tab 1, Alt+2 (KeyEvent.VK_2) to access tab 2 etc. [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> VK_0 thru VK_9 are the same as ASCII '0' thru '9' (0x30 - 0x39)

[[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html%5d)

Tab is `VK_TAB`

Comment: for my first keyEvent. Is it pressing "Shift" key and "1" then the panel on tabbedpane will focus?If so, mime is not working